# How to create MapPolygon object from GeoJSON

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, geojson

I'm trying to decode GeoJSON into an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D so that I can feed it into MapPolygon to create overlays for my map. I'm using [this GeoJSON package](https://github.com/kiliankoe/GeoJSON) to decode my JSON. I'm using the new MapKit for SwiftUI to create the map, and if possible I would like to avoid using UIKit in this project.
The API I'm getting the GeoJSON from will always be a  MultiPolygon or Polygon.

My issue is with putting all of these coordinate pairs into an array so that I can create the polygons on the map. With the GeoJSON package, it uses a switch case to decode the GeoJSON which has proven difficult to iterate through to get all of the pairs. Here is my current code for this:

```
func createPolygons() -> [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
        var polygons = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
        
        for feature in perimeter!.perimeterFeatures.features {
            switch feature.geometry! {
            case .point, .multiPoint, .lineString, .multiLineString:
                break
            case .polygon:
                break
            case .multiPolygon(let multiPolygon):
                var coords = multiPolygon.coordinates.map {_ in
                    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: multiPolygon.coordinates.coordinates.coordinates.latitude, longitude: multiPolygon.coordinates.coordinates.coordinates.longitude) //--> ERROR: Value of type '[Polygon]' has no member 'coordinates'
                }

                return polygons

            case .geometryCollection:
                break
                
            default:
                return polygons

            } //switch case
        } //for loop
        return polygons
    }
```

I haven't found any information on creating MapPolygon from GeoJSON, rather just an array of pre-populated CLLocationCoordinate2D. It seems there aren't many resources on using GeoJSON with Swift in general.

I've also tried creating my own custom struct to decode the GeoJSON into to, ultimately I ran into an issue with tuples not conforming to the Codable protocol.

What would be the best way to resolve this and get these polygons onto the map? Is there a better way to create the MapPolygon from the GeoJSON?

Comment: Do you know [MKGeoJSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkgeojsondecoder)? It's part of MapKit. A third-party library is actually not needed.

Comment: @vadian the GeoJSON I'm using is not standard GeoJSON, at the top level it has an extra key. I have not found a way to use MKGeoJSONDecoder because of this.